# MUI Autocomplete fetch data from request

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I have one annoying problem with autocomplete in MUI 5.

I have several autocomplete components that are connected to huge dictionaries. Because of that, I don't insert the entire collection to "option" param in autocomplete, but call API to search in MongoDB when user inputs something.

In dev env when working with some forms (which have these components) I have a little annoying problem. Some of these components have the option multiple and when I have a value there and start looking for another value in console I have this warning.

```
MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
None of the options match with `{...}`.
You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.
```

Everything works correctly and I have a valid implemented method "isOptionEqualToValue", but because I do not insert the whole dict to option, and when it searches a new value, API filters the collection for the search text.

Autocomplete thinks the values I chose previously are not valid because it is not in the options array, but are valid throughout the collection.

So my question is, can I get rid of this warning or should I do something else?